# Definitions of tensor product

Tags: linear-algebra, tensor-products

For my bachelor thesis as a maths student, I am doing quantum computing, but my professor wanted me to first "master" the tensor product and start my thesis by a chapter about it.

He wanted me to not use the rather boring definition/construction with just using the basis of V and W for V $\otimes$ W.

It would later be really useful if you really understand what a tensor product is, he said. Do you guys recommend some sources or anything? Thank you in advance!

Comment: The wikipedia page is a good start, it also has some references.

Comment: @Stefan i already looked trough wikipedia and it is quite clear with their definitions with the bases, quotiënt space and universal property. But i am not sure wich is like the most general or best definition to start working with? I am not completely sure what is like the best and most general definition?

Comment: @Lowie Without doubt, the universal property is the correct way to think about tensor products. That way you can also define it for modules over a commutative ring, not just for vector spaces.

Comment: I'm really not sure on what "boring definition" should mean. The tensor product is the universal object for which one can factor k-linear maps through.

Comment: thank you for the information! Maybe my professor means the "easy/boring" definition to be the one alot of sites use to just define it for vectors/matrices. But again thanks for the tips!

Comment: @Mark: Well, you can also define it over non-commutative rings, although in general, you only get an abelian group (or a module over the center), unless one of your modules is a bimodule. This level of generality is probably too high for a bachelor thesis, though.

Comment: By the way, you may use `\otimes` for '$\otimes$'.

Comment: @Lowie: By "really understand what a tensor product is", I assume you're supposed to study the universal property and how it is used to prove stuff. But note that the universal property is not a complete definition of the tensor product. One still needs to prove the existence, preferably via the quotient construction. Wikipedia is wrong by calling the universal property and the quotient construction "alternative definitions".

Comment: You'll have to visit the library and check out some algebra textbooks. If you can't find a clean abstract exposition for vector spaces, you could also include books that cover the tensor product of modules. It's not much harder, since you don't want to take any shortcuts by introducing bases anyway.

Comment: @Stefan I wouldn't say that Wikipedia is wrong for calling the universal property a "definition". It's quite common in mathematics that we define something and then prove that the thing being defined is well-defined. What we are doing is stating a property $P(x)$ as the defining property for $x$, and then proving that there is a unique (or, in this case, unique up to unique isomorphism) $x$ such that $P(x)$. The quotient construction is, in a sense, coming up with an alternate defining property $Q(x)$ that the tensor product should satisfy (being a particular quotient of some free module).

Comment: @Mark:  To me, the proof that something is well-defined is part of the definition. Anyway, what I wanted to clarify for the OP was that the quotient construction and the universal property aren't two alternative definitions one can choose from as a matter of taste, but that they complement each other to make up the definition of the tensor product together.

Comment: I advise you to have a look at "**Kronecker product**" which is a good way to convey what tensor product "concretely is" (albeit not an intrinsic way).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is my attempt at explaining what the tensor product "is". Hopefully this will motivate the construction for tensor products and then you can go back to some other resources with fresh eyes and see how the various definitions and properties relate to one another.

Let's start with a thought experiment. Suppose you have two vector spaces $V$ and $W$ (since you seem to be interested in quantum stuff let's assume they are both over $\mathbb{C}$) and you want to create a new vector space $U$ where you can "multiply" vectors in $V$ by vectors in $W$. Formally this means that we have a multiplication map $\mu:V\times W\to U$. Right now, let's just think of this as a set theoretic map. What sort of properties would we like it to have.

First, we would probably like multiplication to distribute over addition in the same way that they do for multiplication and addition of complex numbers (after all $\mathbb{C}$ is a 1-dimensional vector space). In the language of our map this says that $\mu(v_1+v_2,w)=\mu(v_1,w)+\mu(v_2,w)$ and $\mu(v,w_1+w_2)=\mu(v,w_1)+\mu(v,w_2)$.

You would probably also like the scaling in all three of the vector spaces to be "compatible" with each other. In terms of the map this means $\mu(\lambda v,w)=\mu(v,\lambda w)=\lambda\mu(v,w)$. A map with these properties is called *bilinear* (i.e. if you fix the value in one of the slots of the map it is linear in the other slot). This tells us that whatever the tensor product is, it should admit a bilinear map from $V\times W$ into it.

The problem is that there are tons of combinations of vector spaces and maps like this. For instance we could take $U$ to be the trivial vector space and let $\mu$ be the map that takes everything to zero. The good news is that there is a certain universal vector space $V\otimes W$ that admits such a map $\mu:V\times W\to V\otimes W$ (more on how you construct it in a moment). It is universal in the sense that if $\tau:V\times W\to U$ is any other bilinear map then there is a unique **linear** map $\alpha:V\otimes W\to U$ so that $\alpha\circ \mu=\tau$. In other words all bilinear maps factor through linear maps out of the tensor product.

There is a very concrete construction of the tensor product that involves 2 steps. First, take the vector space over $\mathbb{C}$ whose basis consists of the set $V\times W$. We will denote this as $\mathbb{C}(V\times W)$. There is a map $\tilde \mu:V\times W\to \mathbb{C}(V\times W)$ defined by $\tilde \mu(v,w)=(v,w)$. The problem is that this map is not bilinear. For instance, in $\mathbb{C}(V\times W)$, $(v_1+v_2,w)\neq (v_1,w)+(v_2,w)$. To fix this we can take the subspace of $\mathbb{C}(V\times W)$ spanned by elements of the form

- $(v_1+v_2,w)-(v_1,w)-(v_2,w)$ for $v_1,v_2\in V$, $w\in W$
- $(v,w_1+w_2)-(v,w_1)-(v,w_2)$ for $v\in V$ and $w_1,w_2\in W$.
- $(\lambda v,w)-\lambda(v,w)$ for $v\in V$, $w\in W$, $\lambda\in \mathbb{C}$
- $(v,\lambda w)-\lambda(v,w)$ for $v\in V$, $w\in W$, $\lambda\in \mathbb{C}$

and take the quotient vector space, that we now call $V\otimes W$. It is not hard to check that the map $\mu:V\times W\to V\otimes W$ that this induces is bilinear. We essentially concocted the subspace so that this would be the case. It is also not hard to check that it satisfies the appropriate universal property.

One of the great things that falls out of this universal property is that it implies that the tensor product is unique up to canonical isomorphism. What this means is that if you were to come up with some new clever construction for a vector space and a bilinear map that satisfied the same universal property then your clever new construction would be isomorphic to the tensor product I just described via a canonical isomorphism.

Hopefully this helps you get an idea for what the tensor product accomplishes. I would encourage you to go through the details of this and also think about how this construction relates to the "boring" definition using bases of $V$ and $W$. One feature of the "boring" basis approach is that it makes it apparent using that definition that the tensor product of 2 finite dimensional vector spaces is finite dimensional. This is not at all clear from the other construction since we are taking the quotient of an infinite dimensional vector space by an infinite dimensional subspace.

Comment: A big thank you!